# I want to save my parsed HTML file into TXT file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've parsed a web page showing article.
I want to save the parsed data into text file, but my python shell shows an error like this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 107: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and here is a part of my code

```
search_result = urllib.urlopen(url)
f = search_result.read()
#xml parsing
parsedResult = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(f)
linklist = parsedResult.getElementsByTagName('link') #extracting links
extractedURL = linklist[3].firstChild.nodeValue #pick one link
page = urllib.urlopen(extractedURL).read()
#making html file
g= open('yyyy.html', 'w') 
g.write(page)
g.close()
#reading html file and parsing html to get pure text of article
g= open('yyyy.html', 'r')
bs = BeautifulSoup(g,fromEncoding="utf-8")
g.close()
article = bs.find(id="articleBody")
content = article.get_text()
#save as a text file
h= open('yyyy.txt', 'w')
h.write(content)
h.close()
```

What should I add to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
import codecs
h = codecs.open('yyyy.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
```

or using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use unidecode:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

unidecode(page)
```

Comment: there is no such module in my python. how do I get that module?

Comment: h.write(content) << this line

Comment: have you tried `unidecode(content)` ? if not well my answer is useless!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29613/discussion-between-nnaelle-and-user2351602)